# Lossless concatenation of slightly different MP4 files

Tags: mp4

I am trying to combine 2 or more .mp4 videos into a single video (concatenation). But I am getting timestamps errors (with ffmpeg concat demuxer protocol). The videos are very similar (same resolution, fps, etc.), so I'm not sure what is causing this. I am open to trying different tools (hopefully something that runs on linux).

Apparently they are slightly different in some way.

How can I concatenate them, without losing quality?

If you need more information please tell me what command I should run to print the required details.

**Update:** I am trying to concatenate 4 files. I am using the command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy full.mp4
```

where `list.txt` is a text file with the contents:

```
file 1.mp4
file 2.mp4
file 3.mp4
file 4.mp4
```

By request I executed the same command with `-report` as added as the first option. This produced a large log file (110 MB) that you can see here: http://www.filedropper.com/ffmpeg-20180606-024711.

I also ran `ffprobe` on each file, and uploaded the results here:

1. `ffprobe 1.mp4`: https://justpaste.it/64pih
2. `ffprobe 2.mp4`: https://justpaste.it/6r4ig
3. `ffprobe 3.mp4`: https://justpaste.it/77iij
4. `ffprobe 4.mp4`: https://justpaste.it/3xdoi

Comment: Run the same command with -report added and share the report file

Comment: @Gyan The report file is ~ 110 MB (is that normal?). I uploaded it here http://www.filedropper.com/ffmpeg-20180606-024711.

Comment: That's too large. Share output of `ffprobe file` and `ffprobe file2` as well as your command.

Comment: @Gyan Please see edits in the question. I added the requested information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd file is different. You can re-encode it this way,

```
ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -map 0:a -map 0:v
       -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -c:a aac -ar 48000 
       -video_track_timescale 2500   2-new.mp4
```

Depending on how the video in the other files was encoded, you may need to try adding `-bf 1` or `-bf 0`.

Comment: Thanks. The resulting file is almost half-the size (and smaller than what I expect from similar files of similar duration). Is this lossless?

Comment: It uses CRF 23 as default encoding. Add `-crf 18` for visually lossless result